# Welche normative Autorität hat der Duden? / What's the normative authority of the Duden?

Tags: duden, rules

## Frage auf Deutsch

Welche normative Autorität hat der Duden? (Ich beziehe mich hier auf das Wörterbuch.)

## English Question

What's the normative authority of the Duden? (I am referring to the dictionary.)

Comment: Ich habe hier zwar schon geantwortet und die Frage ist ist nett, aber gebe ihr nun leider trotzdem ein -1, da ich kein ["Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs."](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), bzw ["Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour) erkenne.

Comment: @mtwde Ich habe die Frage gestellt, um die Wissenssammlung zu strukturieren, und Diskussionen in Kommentaren zu vermeiden. (Anlass war https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54096/spazieren-walking-in-a-silly-and-affected-manner/54097?noredirect=1#comment131940_54097) Die Frage ist für mich ein Anker für zukünftige Links: Wann immer man den Duden zitiert, kann man hier auf diese Frage verlinken. In diesem Sinne halte ich die Frage für einen sinnvollen Beitrag zu dieser Seite, auch wenn sie keinen eigenen Forschungsaufwand erkennen lässt. Ich war überrascht, dass sie noch nicht existiert.

Comment: Daher denke ich, dass wir das hier als eine Ausnahme der von dir zitierten Regel ansehen sollten. Aber ich kann auch mit dem -1 gut leben und deinen Standpunkt nachvollziehen.

Comment: Ja, leider gibt es keine FAQ hier ^^. Das wäre ein Eintrag dafür oder fürs meta. Mit deiner Intention kann man die Frage aber auch anders stellen. etwa "In vielen Diskussionen (link zum bsp1, 2,3) wird der Duden als ultimative Beleginstanz für blablabla angeführt. Hat der Duden tatsächlich (noch immer) diese normative Autorität? Damit bin ich nicht einverstanden, weil... . Was unterscheidet ihn von anderen Nachschlagewerken? etc. pp. Warum wird nicht wiktionary genommen?" Da gibt es dann immerhin ein konkretes Problem und sicher genausoviele Antworten (oder sogar bessere)^^

Comment: /2 Das erzeugt dann evtl wirklich Diskusionen in den Kommentaren, aber joa, die kann man dann auch in den Chat verschieben wenns ausufert ^^. Wobei die auch hilfreich sein können.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Antwort auf Deutsch

Der Duden ist keine offizielle Autorität mehr. Er hatte diese Rolle von 1955 bis 1995, als die Kultusministerkonferenz der Länder den Duden als verbindliche Autorität für den Schulunterricht vorschrieb. Gegenwärtig hat diese normierende Rolle der Rat für Deutsche Rechtschreibung inne. Mehr Informationen darüber sind unter der Frage [Wer bestimmt, welche Regeln in der deutschen Spache gelten?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15246/wer-bestimmt-welche-regeln-in-der-deutschen-spache-gelten) zu finden.

Damit ist der Duden nun nurmehr ein Wörterbuch. Im Allgemeinen wird die Funktion eines Wörterbuchs darin gesehen, eine *Beschreibung* (*Deskription*) der Sprache und keine *Normierung* (*Präskription*) der Sprache zu liefern. Einerseits lässt sich jedoch auch jede wissenschaftlichen Beschreibung nicht vollständig von normativen Vorstellungen der Beschreibenden trennen, sodass *deskriptive* und *präskriptive* Vorstellungen von reichweitenstarken Wörterbüchern nie völlig voneinander zu trennen sind; andererseits ist der Duden gerade auch aufgrund seiner Geschichte die De-facto-Referenz für unklare Fälle. Im Zweifel über bestimmte Regeln der Orthographie, Interpunktion oder Grammatik, werden die meisten Menschen im Duden nachschlagen.

---

## English Answer

The Duden does not have *official* authority any more. It used to have official authority, from 1955 to 1995, when the *Kultusministerkonferenz der Länder* (*Conference of Ministers of Culture of the German states*), who decides on what is being taught at school, had given it this authority, so that school teachers were bound by Duden rules. Currently, this authority is given to the *Rat der Deutschen Rechtschreibung* (*Council of German Orthography*). More information about this can be found in the thread [Wer bestimmt, welche Regeln in der deutschen Spache gelten?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15246/wer-bestimmt-welche-regeln-in-der-deutschen-spache-gelten) (*Who decides which rules apply to German language?*, in German only).

Nowadays, the Duden has merely the status of a dictionary. In general, the purpose of a dictionary is to *describe* the language, not to *normalize* it. On the one hand, any description of language, even a scientific one, cannot be fully free of normative premises; on the other hand, thanks to its historical role, the Duden is still the *de facto* reference in uncertain cases. If in doubt about certain rules of orthography, punctuation or grammar, most people would consult the Duden.

Comment: Duden ist nicht nur ein Wörterbuch. https://shop.duden.de/Shop/Die-Grammatik-1

Comment: @Dan Der Kommentar passt besser unter die Frage. Unabhängig davon denke ich, dass relativ klar ist, dass mit "der Duden" das Wörterbuch gemeint ist, solange nichts näheres bestimmt ist. Größere Klarheit kann aber nicht schaden, deswegen passe ich die Frage entsprechend an.

Answer (score 8):

Seit der letzten Rechtschreibreform von 1996 dieselbe wie jedes andere Wörterbuch, nämlich praktisch keine. Die "normative Autorität" (falls es so etwas gibt, und zumindestens für die, die sich daran halten **müssen** (alle innerhalb des direkten Einflußbereichs der Staaten, z.B. Schüler, Staatsbedienstete,...) oder **wollen** (alle anderen) hat seither der [Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/)

Anspruch eines guten Wörterbuchs sollte es sein, weitgehend *existierende Sprache zu dokumentieren* anstatt zu *normieren*.

Da es niemanden gibt, der für die große Mehrheit der Sprachnutzer rechtlich bindend vorschreiben kann, was richtig und was falsch ist, betrachten viele Sprachnutzer den Duden allerdings immer noch als eine "Autorität über die deutsche Sprache".

Answer (score 6):

Kurz gesagt: Seit der Neuregelung der deutschen Orthographie im Jahre 1996 keine mehr. Allerdings hat der Duden weiterhin ein so hohes Prestige, dass er nach wie vor vielfach als letzte Berufungsinstanz in Fragen zur deutschen Sprache gilt.

Davor hatte der Duden diese Authorität über 40 Jahre lang offiziell inne, denn die deutsche Kultuministerkonferenz entschied im Jahre 1955:

> Im Zweifelsfällen sind die im 'Duden' gebrauchten Schreibweisen verbindlich.

Allerdings galt der Duden zumindest inoffiziell auch davor als Authorität, denn

> Im Jahre 1915 wurde also der Grundstein für die enorme Bedeutung der Dudenredation für die Geschichte der sprachlichen Zweifelsfälle im 20. Jahrhundert gelegt. [..] Die Auskunftsfreudigkeit der Dudenredation führte dazu, dass eine Instanz entstand, die fortan in allen sprachlichen Fragen und Zweifelsfällen als normative Autorität gelten sollte.

Quelle "[Sprachliche Zweifelsfälle im Deutschen: Theorie, Praxis, Geschichte](https://books.google.de/books?id=yQd2DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false)" von Wolf Peter Klein, Seite 79f

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Würde es dir etwas ausmachen, sie auch auf Englisch zu formulieren? Die Frage war ja auch zweisprachig.

Comment: Der Duden sagt bestimmt auch, dass das "In Zweifelsfällen" sein sollte. :-) Ich kann's nicht editieren, weil's nur ein Zeichen ist.

Comment: Zum Thema "wie schreibt man Autorität" empfehle ich... - den Duden. (scnr) ;)

Comment: @tofro pffff ... das ist doch eindeutig ein Wortspiel um subtil darauf hinzuweisen, dass Konrad Duden der Herausgeber und Author des Ganzen war *hust* ;)

Answer (score 4):

Zu mehr Info über Duden: [Wer bestimmt, welche Regeln in der deutschen Spache gelten?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15246/wer-bestimmt-welche-regeln-in-der-deutschen-spache-gelten)

Im Moment gibt es nur ein verbindliches Regelwerk, und zwar das vom Institut für Deutsche Sprache. https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/regeln-und-woerterverzeichnis/
Allerdings gilt das nur für amtlichen Gebrauch.
Für Privatpersonen oder Angestellte eines Privatunternehmens ist das nicht verbindlich. Deswegen sieht man immer wieder Schreibweisen wie "daß" auf neu ausgestellten medizinischen Unterlagen usw.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Würde es dir etwas ausmachen, sie auch auf Englisch zu formulieren? Die Frage war ja auch zweisprachig.

Answer (score 1):

Ich bin erst heute (Oktober 2023) auf diese Frage aus dem Jahr 2019 aufmerksam geworden, möchte aber zu den bereits gegebenen Antworten noch etwas ergänzen:

---

Über die Rolle des Duden in Deutschland wurde bereits in den vier älteren Antworten berichtet, ich möchte hier auf seine Rolle in Österreich eingehen. Das geht aber nicht, ohne das ÖWB (Österreichisches Wörterbuch) zu erwähnen.

Der Duden hat in Deutschland seit der Rechtschreibreform 1996 dieselbe Autorität, die er in Österreich die ganze Zeit über hatte: Gar keine.

Kurz nach dem Zweiten Weltkrieg wollte das offizielle Österreich so wenig wie möglich mit Deutschland zu tun haben, und distanzierte sich unter anderem auch kulturell von Deutschland. (Vor dem Zweiten Weltkrieg, in den 1930er Jahren, war noch das Gegenteil der Fall, anderenfalls wäre es 1938 gar nicht zur Entfernung Österreichs aus der europäischen Landkarte durch den Anschluss an Deutschland gekommen.) Zu dieser kulturellen Trennung nach 1945 gehörte auch das Kultivieren der sprachlichen Unterschiede, die damals noch deutlich stärker ausgeprägt waren als heute.

Daher entschied man sich als Teil der Errichtung einer eigenen nationalen Identität noch in der Besatzungszeit (die in Österreich bis 1955 dauerte) ein eigenes Wörterbuch herauszugeben, dass die Rechtschreibung des Vokabulars der in Österreich gesprochenen Varietät der deutschen Sprache definiert. Dieses Buch heißt *»Österreichisches Wörterbuch«* (ÖWB) und wurde nicht von irgendwem, sondern von der österreichischen Bundesregierung herausgegeben und war somit ein amtliches Dokument. Die erste Auflage erschien 1951.

Den Duden gibt es zwar schon seit 1880, und er wurde vor der Einführung des ÖWB auch in Österreich verwendet, aber er erlangte erst im Jahr 1955 den Status des offiziellen Regelwerks in Deutschland. In Österreich hatte er diesen Status zu keiner Zeit. Und seit 1951 ist in Österreich auch nicht mehr der Duden das offizielle Nachschlagewerk, das Schülern als Schulbuch gegeben wird, sondern eben das ÖWB.

Als 1996 mit der Rechtschreibreform der Rechtschreibrat gegründet wurde, verlor der Duden zugunsten des Regel- und Wörterverzeichnisses des Rechtschreibrats seinen offiziellen Status in Deutschland. Das ÖWB behielt in Österreich aber seinen offiziellen Status bis heute und wird bis heute im Auftrag der Bundesregierung herausgegeben.

Das ÖWB folgt zwar den Empfehlungen des Rechtschreibrates, aber falls der Fall eintreten sollte, dass diese beiden Regelwerke einander widersprechen, ist in Österreich dem ÖWB der Vorzug zu geben.

Es gibt aber auch beabsichtigte Abweichungen, z.B. diese:

In der Wörterliste des Rechtschreibrats:

> **Geschoss**, Geschoß (*österr.* auch)

Im Österreichischen Wörterbuch:

> **Ge|scho̱ß** das, -es/-e. *auch:* Geschọss; Wurfgeschoß | Erdgeschoß

Beide Wörterbücher zeigen zwar beide Formen an, aber beim Rechtschreibrat ist *Geschoss* die Hauptform und *Geschoß* eine Nebenform, im ÖWB ist es umgekehrt. (Der Grund dafür ist die Aussprache mit kurzem O in Deutschland, aber langem O in Österreich, und das führt aufgrund der gleichen Rechtschreibregeln in D und Ö dazu, dass die Hauptform in einem Land mit SS und im anderen mit ẞ geschrieben wird.)