# "Er wird nach Hause gehen dürfen haben" - Grammatikalisch korrekt?

Tags: modal-verb, auxiliary-verb

Man kann sehr viele Hilfs- und Modalverben aneinanderreihen. Zum Beispiel:

> Er geht nach Hause.

Wir setzen ein Modalverb hinzu:

> Er muss nach Hause gehen.

Was, wenn wir noch Futur I dazusetzen? Dann haben wir:

> Er wird nach Hause gehen müssen.

Was, wenn ich stattdessen Futur II dazusetze? Ich versuche es mal:

> *Er wird nach Hause gehen müssen haben. 
> *Er wird nach Hause gehen gemusst haben.

im Sinne von "Er wird die Verpflichtung gehabt haben nach Hause zu gehen". Welche der beiden obigen Sätze gilt offiziell als grammatikalisch korrekt?

Die zweite Variante klingt bodenständiger, läuft aber Gefahr das Modalverb falsch zu beugen, etwa wie in

> *Er hat nach Hause gehen gemusst. (m.W. falsch) 
> Er hat nach Hause gehen müssen. (korrekt, obgleich künstlich)

Was sagt die deutsche Standardgrammatik dazu?

Comment: Was meinst du mit "offiziell"? Es gibt keine offiziellen Regeln, wie das Deutsche gesprochen werden muss. Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54099/welche-normative-autorit%C3%A4t-hat-der-duden-whats-the-normative-authority-of-th und https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/normative-fragen und

Comment: Die Frage ist nicht per se uninteressant, hat aber wenig praktischen Nutzwert: Wozu die Meinung von Grammatikautoren zu bestimmten Raritäten an grammatischen Erscheinungen ausgraben? Viel Zeitaufwand mit wenig Ertrag. Nach meinem 'Sprachgefühl' wären die 'falschen' (*) Sätze 'korrekt', aber stilistisch schwerfällig und altertümelnd; ich würde bevorzugen _Er musste wohl / vermutlich nach Hause gehen._ Übrigens könnte die beeindruckende Prozession der Verben (regional?) auch eine andere Reihenfolge haben: _wird haben nach Hause gehen müssen._

Comment: Mit den Bewertungen der anderen Sätze stimme ich nicht überein: _Er hat nach Hause gehen gemusst_ ist nicht grundsätzlich, sondern nur standardsprachlich inakzeptabel, umgangssprachlich kommt das vor, und _Er hat nach Hause gehen müssen_ ist für mich keineswegs künstlich, es ist die normal-standardsprachliche Version ('Ersatzinfinitiv' für Partizip 2 bei Modalverben), z.B. _ich hab' das nicht wissen können, das hättest du aber wissen müssen, das hättest du nicht sagen sollen._

Comment: Die Frage in der Überschrift (mit _dürfen_) stimmt mit dem Beispiel im Beitrag (mit _müssen_) nicht überein. Das ist ein wenig verwirrend, da die Beurteilung der Akzeptabilität der beiden nicht übereinstimmen muss. Für mich ist die 'Überschrift-Frage' weniger akzeptabel als dieselbe Frage mit _müssen_, die Perfektformen der Modalverben mit Ersatzinfinitiv sind zwar alle möglich, aber z.B bei _dürfen_ und _sollen_ erscheinen sie mir ziemlich ungebräuchlich.

Answer (score 1):

*Er wird nach Hause gehen müssen.* kann ein zukünftiges Geschehen ausdrücken ("In der Zukunft muss er nach Hause gehen."). In dieser Bedeutung ist die Formulierung heute jedoch ungebräuchlich. Üblicherweise wird das Futur von heutigen Muttersprachlern als Ausdruck einer Vermutung verstanden ("Ich vermute, dass er nach Hause gehen muss."). Die Zukunft wird mit dem Präsens, oft in Verbindung mit Temporaladverbien ausgedückt (*Er muss [morgen] nach Hause gehen.*).

Die Standard- oder Schulgrammatik ist häufig kein guter Ratgeber, wenn man gutes Deutsch lernen möchte. Besser ist es, sich Beispiel am tatsächlichen Sprachgebrauch der Muttersprachler zu nehmen. Die reden und schreiben nämlich nicht grammatisch korrekt!

Dazu muss man wissen, dass die deutsche Grammatik in ihren ersten Entwürfen von der Grammatik des Lateinischen abgeleitet wurde. Dabei wurden grammatische Konstrukte aus dem Lateinischen dem Deutschen "übergestülpt" und dann präskriptiv ausgelegt ("Richtiges Deutsch ist ..."). Neuere Grammatiken gehen einen anderen Weg und versuchen eine vom gesprochenen und geschriebenen Deutsch abgeleitete, deskriptive Grammatik zu entwickeln. So gibt es Grammatiker, die der Meinung sind, dass es im Deutschen keine Tempusformen gäbe, weil die Konjugationsformen des Verbs eben keine zeitliche Bedeutung hätten und Zeitbezüge auf andere Weise ausgedrückt würden.