# Ist der Duden präskriptiv or deskriptiv?

Tags: duden, rules

Was ist der Standpunkt des Dudens in der ganzen Deskriptivismus/Präskriptivismus-Debatte?  Es ist wohl bekannt, dass [das Oxford English Dictionary deskriptiv ist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1AL2EMvVy0) und dass [der Duden formal keine Macht hat](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54099/welche-normative-autorit%c3%a4t-hat-der-duden-whats-the-normative-authority-of-th), und ich glaube mich auch daran erinnern zu können, dass der Duden regelmäßig neue, häufig genutzte Wörter hinzufügt.  Aber was ist die offizielle Position des Dudens, was findet er besser?

Gibt es irgendeine Seite des Dudens darüber (ich kann keine finden), damit ich Andere darauf verweisen kann?

Comment: Wieso `es`, wenn `er` korrekt ist? Und die Klammern vertragen sich m.E. nicht mit dem Alternativstrich - entweder/oder.

Comment: Mit welchem Recht könnte der Duden präskriptiv sein? Dazu müsste er irgendeine Form von Autorität besitzen.

Comment: @tofro Präskriptiv ist eine Herangehensweise und hat nichts mit Autorität zu tun (Beispiel: Bastian Sick).

Comment: @DavidVogt Präskriptive Herangehensweisen stellen *immer* gewisse Forderungen an einen Sollzustand. Dazu ist - selbstverständlich - auch ein gewisses Maß an Autorität (und wenn es nur die "Autorität des Experten" ist) erforderlich, ansonsten sind die Forderungen sinnlos.

Comment: @tofro Wenn du mit Autorität gemeint haben solltest, daß die Leute einer Person oder Institution Glauben schenken, war das "Mit welchem Recht?" irreführend. Daß der Duden Vertrauen genießt, ist offensichtlich. Was war dann dein Einwand an den Fragesteller?

Comment: Als Antwort auf Fragen wird hier regelmäßig auf einschlägige Duden-Paragraphen verwiesen, und zumindest jene, die das tun, messen dadurch - implizit - dem Duden eine gewisse Autorität bei. Ob die tatsächlich existiert und jenes Beimessen gerechtfertigt ist, steht auf einem anderen Blatt. Oft genug, scheint mir, versucht der Duden das RTL2-Nachmittagsprogramm-Deutsch nachträglich zu rechtfertigen.

Answer (score 2):

Mit "der Duden" ist offenbar das Duden-Wörterbuch gemeint (bei der Duden-Grammatik könnte die Frage auch gestellt werden).

Was ich noch weniger zuordnen kann ist die Erwähnung einer "Präskriptivismus / Deskriptivismus"-Debatte. Geht es darum, welche Zielsetzungen ein Wörterbuch verfolgen *soll*? In welchen Bereichen? Ist die Rechtschreibung gemeint, oder die Formenbildung von Wörtern, oder ob man bestimmte Wörter gebrauchen / nicht gebrauchen *soll*?

Bei der Rechtschreibung hält sich der Duden an die amtliche Version des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung, die aber in vielen Fällen Varianten offenlässt. Der Duden spricht davon, in manchen Fällen "Empfehlungen" zu geben, das ist dann offensichtlich genau das, eine Empfehlung, nicht platt präskriptiv. (Da liest man dann solche Sachen wie zB "Als gut lesbar und unmissverständlich gelten dagegen im Allgemeinen die folgenden Fälle; sie werden daher gewöhnlich ohne Apostroph gesetzt:..." https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph#D13; also Empfehlungen gestützt auf Lesbarkeit und andere praktische Aspekte).

Bei der Formenbildung von Wörtern ist immer mal irgendwo was im Fluss, das fällt aber eigentlich in den Bereich Grammatik. Die Duden-Grammatik tut immer beides, darauf verweisen, dass es Variation gibt, auch gelegentlich dass bestimmte Formen "als Standard gelten". Die Duden-Grammatik ist weder deskriptiv noch präskriptiv, sondern in erster Linie eine wissenschaftliche Grammatik, die deskriptive Aspekte und präskriptive Anliegen wiedergibt. Das heißt sie distanziert sich m.E. von präskriptiven Anliegen, blendet sie aber nicht aus, sondern berichtet, dass es irgendwo solche Anliegen gibt.

In der Verwendung des Wortschatzes gibt es meines Wissens keine präskriptiven Zwänge. Der Wortschatz ist von allen sprachlichen Abteilungen die, die sich am zuverlässigsten und am schnellsten verändert, und der Wortschatz unterscheidet sich sowieso immer zwischen verschiedenen Sprachbenutzern. Es gibt das Phänomen, dass der Duden immer mal anfängt, bestimmte Wörter neu zu verzeichnen, das liegt aber eher daran, dass man die Nützlichkeit der Auflistung überlegt, also dass ein Wort gängig genug ist, oder eine deutliche Spezialbedeutung angenommen hat.

Man kann den Duden auch nach seinem Selbstbild befragen, laut Webseite: "Über uns", https://www.duden.de/leitbild. Dort steht nur Bla-Bla. Der einzige sinnvolle Hinweis auf ein Leitbild ist die beiläufige Formulierung "Immer auf der Höhe der Zeit." Das bedeutet, dass man sprachliche Veränderungen mitgeht. Aber über Geschmack lässt sich immer streiten.

Die neue Auflage der Dudengrammatik (2022) hat übrigens eigene Kapitel über Sprachwandel und Gesprochene Sprache. Dort steht all das, wovon in den Foren gesagt wird, dass es verbotenes, schlechtes Deutsch ist :)

Aus dem Vorwort dieser Auflage der Dudengrammatik (S. 22): "Die Grammatik orientiert sich an der geschriebenen Standardsprache, die über- regional, stilistisch neutral, nicht an einen spezifischen Verwendungskontext gebunden und auch in formelleren Kontexten unauffällig ist. Das gilt entsprechend auch bei der gesprochenen Standardsprache, wobei gegebenenfalls ein Blick auf Varianten außerhalb der Leitvarietät gerichtet wird."

Answer (score 1):

Das Online-Wörterbuch des Duden wertet manche Verwendungen als *umgangssprachlich* und versteht darunter *nicht zur Standardsprache gehörend* (siehe https://www.duden.de/hilfe/gebrauch). Es handelt sich um klassische präskriptive Wertungen, soll heißen: Vorurteile, Fehlurteile, Willkürurteile; jedenfalls Wertungen, die sich nicht auf deskriptive Analyse des Sprachgebrauchs stützen. Dazu drei Beispiele.

Unter [Sinn](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sinn) heißt es:

> etwas macht [k]einen Sinn (umgangssprachlich […])

Dabei ist *Sinn machen* sogar in Zeitungstexten häufiger als *Sinn ergeben*. Bei den Verschmelzungsformen sieht es so aus:

1. [*ins*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ins) hat einen eigenen Eintrag und wird nicht als ugs. bezeichnet
2. [*fürs*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fuers) hat einen eigenen Eintrag und wird als "oft ugs." bezeichnet
3. [*vors*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vors) hat einen eigenen Eintrag und wird als ugs. bezeichnet
4. [*gegens*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gegens) hat keinen eigenen Eintrag

Aber Zeitungsbelege für *vors* sind zahlreich und *gegens* findet man auch bei Adorno und Hugo von Hofmannsthal.

> ob er gegen andere sich richtet oder gegens eigene Subjekt.
>
> Indem stiegen Romana und Andreas in dem einen Turm, der gegens Gebirge hin stand, die Wendeltreppe empor.

Sehr merkwürdig auch die Wertung des Plurals [*Tumore*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tumor) als umgangssprachlich; die Form mit *-e* tritt auch in Fachpublikationen auf.

Comment: Was genau macht denn die Aussage "nicht zur Standardsprache gehörend" "klassisch präskriptiv" (solange es durch geeignete Beobachtungen untermauert ist, was du ja nicht ausschließt)

Comment: Das Wörterbuch untermauert leider nie eine seiner Wertungen. Habe jetzt deutlicher formuliert.

Comment: Bekannt sind auch die Beispiele "Schmant" und "Kautsch". Beide waren jahrzehntelang im Duden zu finden, entweder als einzig zulässige oder als bevorzugte Schreibung, obwohl außerhalb der Dudenredaktion jeder "Schmand" und "Couch" schrieb.